# how to take 1 to 3 words of the string?

Tags: java, regex

How do I take from 1 to 3 words of the string? Maximum is 3 words of each line

**For example:**

```
The Pacific Ocean is the largest of the Earth's oceanic divisions
```

**Output:**

```
The pacific Ocean
is the largest
of the Earth's
oceanic divisions
```

---

**Attempt:**

```
    String[] sequences = {""};
    int numberOfSequnces = (int)words.length/3;

    for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
    {
        String word=words[i];
        String sequnce=word;
        for(int m=i+1;m<numberOfSequnces;m++)
        {
            for(int g=m;g<3;g++)
            sequnce +=words[g];
        }

        sequences[i]=sequnce;
    }
```

Problems I have encountered:
Array out of index. I think because of words[g]

Comment: Can you post what you have tried and what problems you encountered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does your "output" actually mean? If just mean print out on console:

```
String[] words = line.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(words[i]);
    if ((i + 1) % 3 != 0) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    } else {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup. I meant to print it out

Comment: Doesn't this print four words on the first line?

Comment: Why not just write `i % 3 != 2` in the parentheses?  Your condition looks far too complicated.

Comment: @DavidWallace I fixed it again. :) I just think `(i + 1) % 3 != 0` is more understandable.

Comment: Well, it's an improvement over what you had a minute ago :-)

Answer (score 2):

This will print your posted output exactly,

```
String line = "The Pacific Ocean is the largest of the "
    + "Earth's oceanic divisions"; // <-- The line.
String[] words = line.split(" ");
int count = 0; // <-- A word count.
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  String word = (words[i] != null) ? words[i]
      .trim() : ""; // <-- Ternary, check for null and consecutive spaces.
  if (word.length() > 0) { // <-- make sure there is a word.
    if (count > 0) { // <-- check the word count.
      if (count % 3 == 0) { // <-- Is it divisible by 3? Newline.
        System.out.println();
      } else { // <-- not divisible by 3, space.
        System.out.print(' ');
      }
    }
    count++; // <-- There is a word, add one to the count.
    System.out.print(word); // <-- print it.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regexp to do that:

```
String sentence = "The Pacific Ocean is the largest of the Earth's oceanic divisions";
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("([^\\p{javaWhitespace}]*\\p{javaWhitespace}){3}", "$0"+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
System.out.println(sentence);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `/(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+)\s+/g`
and replace with `$1\n`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hR5cH7)

Comment: clever way. Would that pattern still be applied to any other strings?